# ImportExport module: can't work custom file adapter in magento2?

Tags: magento2, import

I have rewrite \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import class with function:

```
 protected function _getSourceAdapter($sourceFile)
{
    return 
         \Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Adapter::findAdapterFor(
        $sourceFile,
        $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT),
        $this->getData(self::FIELD_FIELD_SEPARATOR)
    );
}
i have replce adapter
```

> Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Adapter with \Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Adapter

but when i uploading csv and check data process it's give me error 
but if i replace original adapter it works fine

my custom adapter code:

```
namespace Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write;


 class Adapter 
{
/**
 * Adapter factory. Checks for availability, loads and create instance of import adapter object.
 *
 * @param string $type Adapter type ('csv', 'xml' etc.)
 * @param Write $directory
 * @param string $source
 * @param mixed $options OPTIONAL Adapter constructor options
 *
 * @return AbstractSource
 *
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public static function factory($type, $directory, $source, $options = null)
{
    if (!is_string($type) || !$type) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('The adapter type must be a non-empty string.')
        );
    }
   // $adapterClass = 'Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Source\\' . ucfirst(strtolower($type));
    $adapterClass = 'Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Source\\' . ucfirst(strtolower($type));

    if (!class_exists($adapterClass)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('\'%1\' file extension is not supported', $type)
        );
    }
    $adapter = new $adapterClass($source, $directory, $options);

    if (!$adapter instanceof AbstractSource) {
          throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Adapter must be an instance of \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource')
        );
    } 


    return $adapter;
}

/**
 * Create adapter instance for specified source file.
 *
 * @param string $source Source file path.
 * @param Write $directory
 * @param mixed $options OPTIONAL Adapter constructor options
 *
 * @return AbstractSource
 */
public static function findAdapterFor($source, $directory, $options = null)
{
    return self::factory(pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $directory, $source, $options);
}
```

> if (!$adapter instanceof AbstractSource) {
>                 throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
>                   __('Adapter must be an instance of \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource')
>               );
>           } if i am removing this piece of code it's working fine
>   My custom csv code:

```
<?php
```

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Source;

```
   class Csv extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource
  {

   const COL_ATTR_SET="attribute_set_code";
   const VAL_COL_TYPE="downloadable";
   const VAL_ATTR_SET="Migration_Default";

 /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\Write
 */
protected $_file;

/**
 * Delimiter.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_delimiter = ',';

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_enclosure = '';



public function __construct(
    $file,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $directory,
    $delimiter = ',',
    $enclosure = '"'

) {
    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'destruct']);
    try {
        $this->_file = $directory->openFile($directory->getRelativePath($file), 'r');
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException $e) {
        throw new \LogicException("Unable to open file: '{$file}'");
    }
    if ($delimiter) {
        $this->_delimiter = $delimiter;
    }
    $this->_enclosure = $enclosure;
    $this->_counter = 0;
    parent::__construct($this->_getNextRow());
}

protected function _getNextRow()
{
    $parsed = $this->_file->readCsv(0, $this->_delimiter, $this->_enclosure);
    if (is_array($parsed) && count($parsed) != $this->_colQty) {
         $counter = $this->_counter;
        if($counter == 0)
        {
            $parsed[]= \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_TYPE;
            $parsed[]= \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_ATTR_SET;
            $parsed[]= self::COL_ATTR_SET;    
        }
        elseif($counter > 0){
            $parsed[]= self::VAL_COL_TYPE;
            $parsed[]= self::VAL_ATTR_SET;
            $parsed[]= self::VAL_ATTR_SET;       
        }

    $this->_counter = ++$counter;
        foreach ($parsed as $element) {
            if (strpos($element, "'") !== false) {
                $this->_foundWrongQuoteFlag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->_foundWrongQuoteFlag = false;
    }


    return is_array($parsed) ? $parsed : [];
}
public function destruct()
{
    if (is_object($this->_file)) {
        $this->_file->close();
    }
}
 public function rewind()
{
    $this->_file->seek(0);
    $this->_getNextRow();
    // skip first line with the header
    parent::rewind();
}
```

}

Comment: What error that give? can you write that.

Comment: The file "D:/Projects/xampp/htdocs/m2/var/importexport/catalog_product.csv" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(D:/Projects/xampp/htdocs/m2/var/importexport/catalog_product.csv): Permission denied

Comment: Can you write whole error log trace because above is warning and you have written unlink ?

Comment: yes this warning is occur due to custom adapter  when i replace it with original one it's not giving any warning

Comment: can you check header name is proper in csv file may this message is misleading as per: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6658

Comment: No issue with header, please check in question i have added more info @FeedlayTechnologies

Comment: you have also override class Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Source\Csv  ? at Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Source\Csv

Comment: because this line : $adapterClass = 'Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Source\\' . ucfirst(strtolower($type));   create object of  Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Source\Csv   and check that is instanceof AbstractSource

Comment: yes i have created  Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Source\Csv  but i  am getting false it instanceof AbstractSource

Comment: you have extended with : Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Source\Csv or  \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource

Comment: i have added my custom csv code in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80761/discussion-between-feedlay-technologies-and-rutvee-sojitra).

Comment: if (!$adapter instanceof AbstractSource)  replace with if (!$adapter instanceof Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource)

Comment: in file Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Adapter :
if (!$adapter instanceof AbstractSource) replace with if (!$adapter instanceof Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file

> Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Adapter

`if (!$adapter instanceof AbstractSource)` 
replace with 
`if (!$adapter instanceof Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource)`